# How to view JavaScript error messages in Safari 6 (Mountain Lion)

Tags: javascript, safari, osx-mountain-lion

I'm using Safari 6 that came with Mountain Lion. They changed everything about the web inspector and I'm lost.

When I get an uncaught JavaScript error Safari helpfully pauses execution, zooms to the file and line that's broken, displays the call stack on the left and local variables on the right.

But where is the text describing the error? It's not in the logs. None of the little tabs on the left or right show anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the message appears in Current Log only if you try to continue execution by clicking "Continue script execution" button.

To me this strikes a bit odd too. Maybe worth a bug report at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/?

Comment: Yeah, maybe. I did find that error message eventually. But I also noticed that the console lags when outputting, and you can't mouse over variables to inspect their contents any more. Very disappointed.